# Is it possible develop Xamarin.iOS without MAC and use free account?

Tags: ios, xamarin

As Title

Is it possible develope Xamarin.iOS without MAC and use free account?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+without+mac+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 Use Free Apple development account without team,connect iPhone run Xamarin.ios app. vs2022 show select team but no team list. Debug Stop here!!

Comment: Looks like it's not possible when you use `Visual Studio 2022`.

Answer (score 0):

Intel PC install VMbox with Monterey and Xcode
use free Apple acount

VS2022 pair PC MAC
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).